# Crontab SVN Daily Commits

Tags: php, svn

I got a shared hosting account and am a php developer.  Would it be possible to use cron and a bash script to daily commit a new copy of my developing code to svn for I don't have to worry about doing it myself?  If so, any links to where I can find tutorial-like articles to do this?

Note, I know this may commit non-working code to a svn repo which may leave a bad taste in many peoples mouths, but I'd like to do it regularly anyway.

Comment: People generally track changes by feature or bugfix, not by day. You would essentially end up with a repository full of commits that say "Changes for (insert date here)". Is that really what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed to run Crons, you could try a simple shell script like so:

```
cd /path/to/code/directory
svn commit -m "Daily commit of all code"
```

Basically just save this as "daily_commit.sh" and have the cron job system execute it on a daily basis.

Comment: yeah, but I want to commit on certain parts of the shared server code, Would this whole thing not be able to think on its feet if I start adding new code files?

Comment: For new files you would have to do an `svn add` first. But i really you sholdnt need to commit anything on a server nayway because you *SHOULD* be working locally and only pushing to a server for testing or deployment.

Comment: If you created new files and want them to be added, you would either need to type in `svn add [filename]` yourself, or you could try adding `svn add *` just before the `commit` line, but I'm not 100% sure on how good that will work and how secure it would be.